# How can I change the colour of a bottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter

How can I change the colour of a `bottomNavigationBar`?

Here below is a snippet of my code. I am unable to change the color of the widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(

      currentIndex: currentIndex,
      onTap: (selectedPosition) => onNavItemTapped(selectedPosition),
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        widget.buildBottomNavigationBarItem(
            context, 'Discover', Icons.home, false, 0),
        widget.buildBottomNavigationBarItem(
            context, 'Chats', Icons.chat, true, 1),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your BottomNavigationBar inside Material widget and provide color property as

```
Material(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child:BottomNavigationBar(),
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Please use like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
          canvasColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          ..........
```

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer as it works properly with the latest version of Flutter SDK

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `backgroundColor` of the `BottomNavigationBarItem` like this:

```
return new BottomNavigationBar(
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.library_books, size: 22.0),
              title: new Text("Text", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0)),
              backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
            ),
     ],
 );
```

Comment: This works perfectly but I wonder why backgroundcolor of BottomNavigationBar didn't worked but backgroundColor of BottomNavigationBarItem worked and setting background color in one item works for every item.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the bottom bar with a Theme call where you patch the Theme data with canvasColor and primaryColor.

```
Theme(
   data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
     // background
     canvasColor: Colors.red, 
     // active item foreground
     primaryColor: Colors.white  
     // inactive items foreground
     textTheme: TextTheme(caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45)) 
   ),
   child: BottomNavigationBar()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the color of BottomNavigationBar everywhere in your app try changing the canvas color in your main widget like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      //here 
      canvasColor: Color(0xff1A535C),
    ),
    home: HomePageOrAnyThingElseAsYouWant(),
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar's background color is the default Material background color, so just wrap your [BottomNavigationBar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) in a Material Widget

```
return Material(
color : Colors.red,
child:new BottomNavigationBar(

      currentIndex: currentIndex,
      onTap: (selectedPosition) => onNavItemTapped(selectedPosition),
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        widget.buildBottomNavigationBarItem(
            context, 'Discover', Icons.home, false, 0),
        widget.buildBottomNavigationBarItem(
            context, 'Chats', Icons.chat, true, 1),
      ],
    ));
```

Comment: still not change the background color of bar

Comment: this is not helpful any details ?

Answer (score 0):

The bottomNavigationBar has a field called backgroundColor. Setting this field changes the color.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(

        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old and it's easy to figure it out,

But i will demonstrate to help other for new Flutter SDK. Let's have an example to be clear what we are taking about =>

```
BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
             backgroundColor: Colors.green,
             label: text,
             icon: AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: Duration(
                         milliseconds: AppAnimationDuration.MEDIUM_ANIMATION_DURATION,
                     ),
              width: isSelected ? AppIconSize.size23 : AppIconSize.size20,
              height: isSelected ? AppIconSize.size23 : AppIconSize.size20,
              child: Container(
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                iconPath,
                                 color: Colors.amber,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
),
```

The first property in the BottomNavigationBar is backgroundColor,

And this property is responsible of the whole color of the BottomNavigationBar widget.

So it will color the whole background of the widget in fill way.

And the Second property also backgroundColor in BottomNavigationBarItem Widget is responsible of the background color of single item in BottomNavigationBar.

I hope this will help some people.